# Download popup not coming in IE11

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am not able to downloading a file in IE 11 with my application and others can downloading in IE 11. I tried with so many options like enabled the downloads tab in security settings. But not able downloading it.So please tell me , how can download it automatically , when  click the link.

Thanks,
Narsi p

Comment: Its not working only for your application ?

Comment: its not working only for me. That download functionality is working for all other user.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Disabling PoP up blocker.

Tools--> Internet options--> security--> Click on Custom Level Button-->Change **Use Pop-up** **Blocker** as "**Disable**"